# Subscipted Text in Visual Studio Labels

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Since I can not have more than one Font specified for a Label in a Visual Studio 2010 project, so I attempted to use two Labels to give the effect of text with a subscript.

Even with Margin and Padding set to "0,0,0,0" I still get the background of one label covering the text of the other.  The picture as the bottom shows the best I can get it.

Is there a way to really make the label extend 0 pixels beyond the text in the label?

[image]

Here are some pictures of the TextAlign properties for the labels.  It seems they're set correctly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not simply set the BackColor to Transparent, as this text displays over the top of a RectangleShape.  If I set the Label BackColor to Transparent, it changes to the color of the Form and not the color of the RectangleShape!

Answer (score 0):

With the padding you set it should work however, you probally need to also  `Right Align` the Label on the left-hand side and `Left Align` the Label on the right-hand side.

Comment: In my picture, the "V" label has its TextAlign property set to MiddleRight and the "OUT" label has its TextAlign property set to MiddleLeft.  I'm still getting the overlap problem, however.

Comment: You sure?. A non-padded label aligned to the right should align with a non-padded label to the left with a 1px boundary. Are you not seeing this?

Comment: I added more pictures to show the outline of the labels, along with their TextAlign properties.  I can't seem to get a 1px boundary, even though the Padding and Margin are all 0s.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's are the settings of the labels where you're seeing the 1px boundary?  Other than the defaults I mean...what's the font and anything else that's not the default?  If I can recreate the correct behavior you're seeing, then I can figure out which difference is causing it not to work in my example.  You are using VS2010?